# Ruby .each efficiency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, activerecord

I do (in my view):

```
# myUser is a User in ActiveRecord with :has_many :posts
myUser.posts.each do |post|
end
```

If the user had ten posts, would this be doing a database call ten times? Should these loops be like (less pretty)?:

```
myPosts = myUser.posts
myPosts.each do |post|
end
```

[Here](http://pastebin.com/KEv77yzX) is a paste bin of a ruby file that I did to test. **EDIT** Modified the paste bin.

This reminds me of code in Java

```
for (int i = 0; i < someExpensiveFunction(); i++)
```

that should be (unless the array is modified)

```
for (int i = 0, len=someExpensiveFunction(); i < len; i++)
```

Am I missing something? I see a bunch of rails examples where people loop through some `has_many` field of an object. This is important to me as I'm trying to optimize my application's performance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> If the user had 10 posts, this would technically be doing a database call 10 times?

Nope.

```
myUser = User.find 123
myUser.posts.each do |post|
  puts post.title
end
```

This code here will run 2 queries. The first will find a user by its id, returning a single row.  The second will run a query asking for all posts which have a user id that matches `myUser`.  Then the `each` will use the result of that to iterate through.

---

If you watch the log in development mode it tells you the queries it's running, and you should see a single query returning all those posts.

Rails uses an association proxy object to hold your query, execute the query when you need records, and then *caches the result*.  It's a very helpful bit of code and, for the most part, it handles things like this for you.

This is a feature of *Rails*, not ruby.

---

At the ruby level, `each` simply acts on collections.

```
def get_letters
  puts 'executing "query"'
  sleep(3)
  ["a","b","c"]
end

get_letters.each do |item|
  puts item
end
```

This should print out.

```
executing "query"
a
b
c
```

The `get_letters` method executes, it returns an array, an that array already full of data is what we call the `each` method on, so we can process each item.  Fetching the collection and iterating through it are 2 completely separate steps.

---

From your pastebin:

```
# will this run forever?
myArr = ["a","b","c"]
myArr.each do |item|
  myArr.push("x")
end
```

Yeah it will, But not because the array is being "fetched" over an over.

This equivalent to javascript like this, which spells it out better.

```
myArr = ["a","b","c"];
for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
  myArr.push('x');
}
```

The original array, on *each iteration* of the loop checks to see if it's done yet. But because the array gets longer by one every single time we progress by one item, `i < myArr.length` will always be `true` because they both increase by one on each iteration. The same thing is going on in ruby with your `each` loop, for the same reason.

It runs forever, not because you keep running some code to regenerate the array. It runs forever because you are artificially mutating the resulting array.

Comment: Thanks, but question. On my paste bin as the last example, the loop runs forever... I don't quite get why it would if the result would be "cached" does Ruby modify the cache afterwards? What would happen if I add a post in a .each loop of posts?

Comment: @K2xL See my edit, which explains things more at the base ruby (non rails) layer. But your loop, as posted, most certainly does _not_ "run forever". After 3 seconds, it's done.

Comment: @K2xL You are modifying the array you're iterating through. This is usually a very bad idea. See my last update...